# how to Send an SMS through java by using twilio sdk

Tags: twilio

I am trying to send an sms from twilio API,but i am getting an error for the `getMessageFactory()`.

`MessageFactory messageFactory = client.getAccount().getMessageFactory();`

The method `getMessageFactory()` is undefined for the type Account

what is the problem ?

I am pasting entire code below :

```
import java.util.*; 
import com.twilio.sdk.*; 
import com.twilio.sdk.resource.factory.*; 
import com.twilio.sdk.resource.instance.*; 
import com.twilio.sdk.resource.list.*; 

public class TwilioTest { 
 // Find your Account Sid and Token at twilio.com/user/account 
 public static final String ACCOUNT_SID = "[Accountsid]"; 
 public static final String AUTH_TOKEN = "[AuthToken]"; 

 public static void main(String[]args) throws TwilioRestException { 
  TwilioRestClient client = new TwilioRestClient(ACCOUNT_SID, AUTH_TOKEN); 

   // Build the parameters 
   List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(); 
   params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("To", "+16518675309")); 
   params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("From", "+14158141829")); 
   params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Body", "Hey Jenny! Good luck on the bar exam!")); 


   MessageFactory messageFactory = client.getAccount().getMessageFactory(); 
   Message message = messageFactory.create(params); 
   System.out.println(message.getSid()); 
 } 
}
```

I added all the required jars file and account sid and authtoken which i got from registering on twilio.com website i added valid phone nos

Comment: could you post the stacktrace of the error?

Comment: Hey, could you post the entire code you're using to send the message? Thanks

Comment: Hey @Hari Krishna. Did you solved your problem? If yes, How?

Answer (score 0):

Are you on a free trial account using the [java helper library](https://www.twilio.com/docs/java/install)? If so, you will want to double check that you're following a few [key steps](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/twilio-basics/how-does-twilios-free-trial-work):

- Be sure to verify any non-Twilio phone number before sending or
  receiving any SMS messages to/from it.
- You will be able to send SMS from your Twilio SMS enabled number, but not from your verified personal number. This rule will also apply
  after the trial.
- Alphanumeric Sender IDs cannot be used with trial accounts.
- You may be eligible to use Global SMS on your trial account. If this is something you're attempting [learn more here](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/can-i-try-twilios-global-sms-without-upgrading).